# How to find which number of orders for a customer

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

Given a table *orders*

| id | customer_id | created_at |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2022-09-01 |
| 2 | 2 | 2022-09-02 |
| 3 | 1 | 2022-09-03 |
| 4 | 1 | 2022-09-04 |
| 5 | 2 | 2022-09-04 |

How do I produce a column that describes which number in the series for the customers the order is?

Example

| id | customer_id | created_at | order number |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2022-09-01 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 2022-09-02 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 | 2022-09-03 | 2 |
| 4 | 1 | 2022-09-04 | 3 |
| 5 | 2 | 2022-09-5 | 2 |

Comment: Where does row 5 come from in the result when you have only 4 in source? Also research ROW_number window function. Try coding and post code if you still have problems https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_row-number

Comment: @P.Salmon I was missing a row in source table. I'll take a look, thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use a window function for that. With a cumulative count over a partition by customer id, you get exactly the order number you need:

```
select orders.*, 
       count(*) over (partition by customer_id order by id) order_number
from   orders
order by id;
```

In MySQL 5.7 you could do this:

```
select customer_id, 
       (select count(*) 
          from orders 
         where customer_id = main.customer_id and id <= main.id)
from   orders main;
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this in MySQL 5.7?

Comment: Are you on MySQL 5.7? Then please tag your question also with `mysql-5.7`